# I need to upgrade my laptop wifi 2.4GHz frequency to 5GHz frequency

Tags: network-adapter, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

My university has wifi routers that support both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz. My Asus laptop is 802.11b Preamble, therefore I can use only 2.4 GHz. It is too slow to use university wifi. My other friends has wifi adapters that support 5GHz frequency in their laptops, thus they have better connection speed than me

How can I upgrade my laptop to use 5GHz wifi without changing any internal devices? Can I use a wifi adapter to speed up my internet? After using a wifi adapter can I use 5GHz frequency like my other friends?

Comment: All you need to do is buy a 802.11ac USB wifi adapter. They're not expensive.

Comment: @n8te 802.11n adapters also support 5GHz and they're even cheaper

Comment: @phuclv - True. I stand corrected.

Comment: Are you sure that your laptop really only supports 802.11**b**? 802.11g was standardized around 2003; any laptop made in the last 10 years should support that.

Comment: "802.11b preamble" is a compatibility setting, and does not mean that the whole NIC is 802.11b-only. It might very well go up to 802.11n... just be 2.4 GHz only.

Comment: It has 802.11b,802.11g,802.11n when i type in cmd. But when i find it in device manager>network adapter>Qualcomm>advance> It has 802.11b preamble, "Adhoc 11n", Recieve Buffers, Scan Valid interval, Transmit Buffers. when i connect wifi my internet is slower than others, I think my laptop doesnt support 5Ghz frequency. Thats why i want to find a method to get speed internet. -@grawity,-@duskwuff

Comment: please check the adapter model and put it here. Those "preamble" options are not relevant to the operating frequency

Answer (score 1):

What frequency bands you can use is determined mostly by the physical radio transmitter/receiver on your Wi-Fi adapter. The rest of the computer doesn't matter at all. When you buy a new Wi-Fi adapter (whether internal or USB), it will have its own radio – that's the whole point.

Note that the frequency band isn't the only factor – the standard revision also matters (802.11 a/b < g < n < ac < ax), features such as MIMO also contribute to the overall maximum speed.

So buy a USB Wi-Fi adapter that supports 802.11ac if you want best performance, or at least 802.11a+b+g+n as the bare minimum. (The combination of *a + n* indicates 5 GHz support, while *n* on its own doesn't... but I assume most products will simply have "2.4 & 5 GHz" written on the box.)